# java open file xlsx

Tags: java, netbeans

how do I open the excel file located inside my project?

[image]

I would like to press a jbutton and open file1

Answer (score 0):

What would you like to do with it? If you just want to handle the data of the Excel-file, I would export my Excel-file to a csv-file (in Excel 2016: File > Export > Change File Type > CSV (Comma delimited)).

The delimiter used for separating data depends on your system settings (mine is set on semicolon to eliminate annoying situations with commas in the cells).

The advantage of a CSV-file is that you can handle the file as any other text file.

Inside the actionPerformed-method of your JButton, you can open the file using:

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("my_csv_file.csv"))) {
    // do anything you want with the file using the scanner object
    // for example, print all data to the screen:
    // make sure you import java.util.Scanner, java.io.File and java.io.FileNotFoundException
    // and catch a FileNotFoundException or throw it to be handled anywhere else
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String data[] = sc.nextLine().split(";");
        for (String s : data) {
            System.out.print(s + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```